# Should I use pointer-events?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, hover

I have a hover effect applied to the featured image of my posts that works, (my site is basically a grid of featured images). I was able to get the post title to display overtop of the featured image and I set the size of the post title to 100% width and height with a colored background.

My problem is that the image was the link, and when it is hovered over it covers the image and I can't click the link.

I researched into using `pointer-events: none;` as a possible solution.

But, there has been mixed views on if it is cross browser compatible and/or if it should be used.

If no, is there a way to make the bottom link click-able through the hover event?

css code

```
.box-title {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 99%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.title-styling {
position: relative;
margin-top: 40%;    
}

.hover-decal:hover > .box-title {
display: block;
}
```

html code

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-md-4 col-sm-4 pbox '); ?>>

<div class="hover-decal">

      <div class="box-title"><div class="title-styling"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div></div>
      <!-- <div class="box-meta"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div> --!> 

    <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 560, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>  

        <?php if($image) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

---

Also, I have managed to make the site-title text as a link to the post as well (but it is small compared to the image). Is there a way to make the 'background' of the title part of the link while still covering the image?

Comment: Please create a fiddle or a code snippet to recreate the issue

Comment: I have found a work-around, sloppy and everything so I would still like to hear solutions. But I basically was able to stack three links on top of each other to create the effect